# Java web start error after update Java 7u17 to Java 8u25 SecurityException

Tags: java, java-web-start, jar-signing

Java web start error after update Java 7u17 to Java 8u25

```
SecurityException com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningExceptions: Found unsigned entry in resource:
```

My application deploy via JWS using self sign method.

I use JDK6 to generate keystore, cert and sign the jar. And use JRE7u17 (actually start from JRE6u21 then update it along the way) on client side to load `jnlp` file and start the application.

Everything works fine until I update client JRE to the newest one which is 8u25. Then I double click shortcut as always to start the application. However the below error occur.

All environments are on Windows

```
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource:(http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app/app.jar, 0.2.2.01)
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The error said about unsigned entry, but I didn't modify the application jar at all. Therefore, I think that it was properly signed.

I tried to search around the internet and didn't find specific solutions, so I would like your help to resolve this problem.